# OST File Processing

Tags: outlook-redemption

We are using C#.net version.

I want to process OST File in same manner as PST file processing.
Does it possible using Redemption or any other method ?
Or if there any way we can save Message from OST using Redemption..

Can you advise.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no publicly available API for accessing the standalone OST file - they can only be used in the context of a profile that created them.

OST file format is not documented, but its closely related to PST, which is documented.